# NVIDIA Video Engine Utilization

Tags: nvidia, flash, video-player

I've realized that the majority of the Linux distributions and their video player applications, even Adobe Flash Player, don't use Video Engine Utilization, and I want to know why? Because at least on Windows this technology works very well, and this reduced the load on the CPU a lot. I am hoping to get your opinions. Thanks! I am using the Nvidia proprietary driver.

The comparison:
On Linux it's Video Engine Utilization in NVIDIA X Server Settings for Nvidia graphics driver 331.49.
On Windows it's Video Engine Load in GPU-Z with Nvidia driver as well.
I hope this is understandable.

The below screenshot shows the Sensors tab of the GPU-Z application in Windows:

[image]

The next screenshot shows the NVIDIA X Server Settings window in Ubuntu:

[image]

Comment: [link](http://gpuz.techpowerup.com/14/03/03/bbz.png) Video Engine Load is the comparative with Video Enginer Utilization on linux

Comment: The _Psensor_ application has some, but not all, of the information in your screenshot that is missing from the nvidia-settings (NVIDIA X Server Settings) application which you mentioned in your question.

Comment: [link](https://twitter.com/ricardocanul7/status/440369451922227202/photo/1) here is it

Comment: Same "problem" here. It seems that not many video players / web browsers on GNU/Linux are making advantage of GPU video acceleration...